# Objective C Get Dictionary from Array[i]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries that populate a tableView as seen below

```
self.tableCell.usernameLabel.text = [self.loadTableArrayCopy[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"user.full_name"];
```

If the user likes the content of the row, they can press a save button on the cell and certain values from the dictionary are saved in Core Data.

The problem: not all values from the dictionary correspond to outlets in the uitableviewcell. If that were not the case, I could do something like this

```
savedItem.username = self.tableCell.usernameLabel.text
```

But since some values, such as thumbnails, are not displayed in the cell, I am not sure that I could do something like this since it's not associated with a cell

```
savedItem.thumbnail = self.thumbnail
```

My preferred option is to take the indexPath.row, access the dictionary at array[indexPath.row] and save by setting the managed object's properties from the dictionary. How can I get this dictionary out of the array and into a local variable so I can do something like this?

```
savedItem.thumbnail = [myLocalDictionary valueForKeyPath@"thumbnail"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user tap save button then you could get the indexPath.row value.So later,

```
NSDictionary *saveDict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This way to will get dictionary and could further save it to coreData.

If not able to find indexPath.row value from button then you could do as below:-

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *senderBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
  UITableViewCell *cell;

  if (![Utilities isIPhone]) {
     if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.intValue < 7)
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[senderBtn superview] superview] superview];
     else
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[[senderBtn superview] superview] superview] superview];
  }
  NSIndexPath *index =  [advancedSearchTable indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

When save is tapped you could add above lines and find out index(indexPath). Later, use index to get dictionary from array.

Comment: cool, objectAtIndex is the method I was looking for. I was searching NSDictionary init methods to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single section, you can do it easily:

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set this:

```
cell.saveButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

From save button event do this:

```
-(void)savePressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = btn.tag; // This is your selected row.
    NSDictionary *youDictionary = [array objectAtIndex:row];

}
```